# How to calculate area of an organic shape?

Tags: ios, shapes, area

I want to know its possible to calculate the area of an organic shape. The shape im trying to calculate looks something like this: [image]

Imagine its drawn by `CGPoints`

Is there a special function for this? Im thinking maybe CoreImage or Quartz or maybe opengl.

Comment: In what sense is it "drawn by CGPoints"? Also, do you know how to integrate?

Comment: I mean that every corner is a point, it isnt drawn its just points, i just drew it so you guys can see what kindof shape im talking about, no i dont know how or what integrate is.

Comment: Oh i looked up what integrate is, I know how to do it, it isnt called that in my country :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the boundary path consists only of straight line segments and does not intersect
itself then you can use the
following formula to compute the area of the enclosed region (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Area_and_centroid):

```
CGPoint points[N]; 

CGFloat area = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    area += (points[i].x * points[(i+1) % N].y - points[(i+1) % N].x * points[i].y)/2.0;
}
```

where `points[0], ... , points[N-1]` are the starting points of the line segments in counter-clockwise order.

For more complicate path segments such as Bézier curves, you can subdivide each segment
into small parts that can be approximated by line segments.

Comment: What does the % do? some sort of division?

Comment: % is modulo, or remainder after integer division.

Comment: @Arbitur: One step of the summation accesses `points[i]` and `points[i+1]` which are the start and end point of the i-th line segment. For the last step (i = N-1) this should "wrap around" to `points[N-1]` and `points[0]`. The modulo operator is just a convenient way to get this "wrap around" because `N % N = 0`. If you look at the formula and the picture in that Wikipedia article then you will probably understand it. - But please let me know if you need more help!

Comment: So 10 % 3 = 7 as I understand from bobnobles answer.

Comment: @Arbitur: 10 % 3 = 1 (the remainder if you divide 10 by 3), and 10 % 7 = 3.

Comment: @Arbitur: The only important point of the modulo operator in this formula is that `i % N = i` for `i = 0, ..., N-1`, and `N % N = 0`, so that in the last step of the summation (i=N-1), `points[(i+1) % N] = points[0]`. The endpoint of the last path segment is the starting point of the first segment. - I hope that helps to understand the formula!

Comment: Hm so it makes it calculate the area from the other direction? like when the index should be 0 its N and when it should be N its 0?

Comment: @Arbitur: The first segment is from `points[0]` to `points[1]`. The second segment is from `points[1]` to `points[2]`, ... and so on. Now the *last* segment is not from `points[N-1]` to `points[N]` but  from `points[N-1]` to `points[0]`, and that is achieved by the modulo operator.

Comment: I read some examples on the web and now I think Ive got it. 2%2=0 because 2 can only go in 2 1 time and leaves 0 to waste. 7%3=1 because 3 can only go in 7 2 times and leaves 1 to waste.