# How to calculate the inside area of a closed shape given a set of coordinates describing the that shape

Tags: python, arrays, area

I have two arrays https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EyfL.png, first one is y coordinates and the second one is x coordinates, when I plot a diagram with these coordinates, it becomes a closed shape like the attached image https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOQ7A.png, I'm asking for a way to calculate the inside area of this closed shape in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the code here: [Calculate area of polygon given (x,y) coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467972/calculate-area-of-polygon-given-x-y-coordinates)

```
def PolyArea(x,y):
    return 0.5*np.abs(np.dot(x,np.roll(y,1))-np.dot(y,np.roll(x,1)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

[How to calculate area of an organic shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18166263/how-to-calculate-area-of-an-organic-shape)

Check out this link, I think it has the same question as you.

Even though it uses another language, you can try and convert it to Python code.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very helpful

Comment: Yup! No problem.